# Visual Basic - Execute a code every last day of the month

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, vba

I'm developing an inventory with accounting system, I have a code that getting the beginning/ending inventory of every month and save it to my database (SQL Server 2008).

My system right now is capable of getting the beginning/ending inventory of every month if the date is **EXACTLY** the last date of the month.

For example if date today is June 30, 2014, then when the user log on in the system my code will execute. Now, my problem is, if the last day of the month is non-working day then the user will not use the system and maybe use it on the next working day.

I used DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now) + 1, -1) for getting the last day of the current month.

I need to execute my code if the date is last day of the month or greater.

Comment: A little more precision needed - every day is the last day of the month or greater.

Comment: Does your code produce a txt log? If not, you may want to add simple code just to create a blank txt file with the date of code execution. Then alter your code to check for most recent execution and action if needed. Have you consider a user log out and back in on the day it should back up?

Comment: @Dale M - I need to execute my code if it the date is the last day of the current month or greater. For example today is June 15, 2014 then my code will not execute But if its June 30, 2014 and so on then it does.

Comment: @PatricK my code does not produce a txt log. I'm not familiar with it but I will try, I got an idea because of what you said. Thanks

Comment: But July 15 *is* greater that June 30.

Comment: @user3579618 The simplest way to create a text file at a shared location is to use [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. You are writing to a table in SQL Server, I assume that this is dated with the relevant month. Write a short piece of code to get the maximum date stored in your table, compare it to today's date and run the code if appropriate.

Today is 15 July 2014, if the `MAX` in your table is 30 June 2014 do nothing, if it is 31 May 2014 run your code.

Comment: I got what you said, but like what I said in my question. What if that last day of the month is holiday or the company is close for some reason so then the system will not be used. If that day is June 30, 2014. The company will use the system in next working day for example July 1, 2014. Meaning the ending inventory for the month of June 2014 is not stored in my database.

Comment: But if the company is closed on June 30, then the opening inventory on the next day is open cannot have changed. To be honest, I think you have bigger problems with your model - what happens to your June closing inventory if, on 4 July, I change a sale dated 23 June?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I solved my problem using this code

I check if the date TODAY is equal to last day of the current month.

If Format(Date.Now, "MM/dd/yyyy") = DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now) + 1, 0) Then

```
//get the last day of the current month

monthdate = DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now) + 1, 0)
```

Else

```
//get last day of the previous month

monthdate = DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now) + 0, 0)
```

End If

Then I have a query that will check my table if there's already a date that equal to monthdate

if there is

exit sub

otherwise execute code that will get/insert the ending inventory. :D